# Get post by Category in custom template

Tags: categories, get-post

I want get all categor  and after that i want get 5 post per category. but my code not work! 
http://pastebin.com/vxDSGGZk

```
<?php
    $categories=get_categories('');
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        echo '<p> Cat ID: '. $category->cat_ID. '</p>';

        // The Query
        $id_cat = $category->cat_ID;}
        $args = array(
            'cat' =>  $id_cat,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );
        query_posts( $args );

        // The Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            the_title();
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;
    }

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

please help me! thanks!
P/s:this is the first time i ask on here and i can't paste code in here. please check link pastebin.

Comment: Please do not link code from external sources - always put everything one needs to understand your problem into your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$categories=get_categories('');
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Cat ID: '. $category->cat_ID. '</p>';

    // The Query
    $id_cat = $category->cat_ID;
    $args = array(
        'cat' =>  $id_cat,
        'showposts' => 5,
    );
    query_posts( $args );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;
}

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: try above code , there was a error in loop.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?